# Find $\lim_{x \to 2} f(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits

**Q**:If $\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{f(x)-5}{x-2}=3$ then find $\lim_{x \to 2} f(x)$
**My approach**:Suppose $\frac{f(x)-5}{x-2}=ax+b\Rightarrow f(x)=(ax+b)(x-2)+5$
$\lim_{x \to 2} f(x)=\lim_{x \to 2}(ax+b)(x-2)+5=5$
Is it right??Because it is not necessary that  $\frac{f(x)-5}{x-2}$ could be a linear.If i am wrong then please correct me.Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: Why do you assume that $\;\frac{f(x)-5}{x-2}=ax+b\;$ is a linear function? This is not necessarily true. The result is correct, though.

Comment: Hint: you can multiply both sides by $\lim_{x\to 2}(x-2)$

Answer (score 4):

I thing that 
$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}(f(x)-5)+\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}5
=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\dfrac{f(x)-5}{x-2}(x-2)+\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}5=3.0+5=5 $
since every limits are finite value.

Comment: +1 for a simple and direct approach.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is incorrect, as you say, you make the false assumption that $$\frac{f(x)-5}{x-2}$$ is a linear function.

---

To actually answer the question, first answer the following question (consider this a **hint**):

> If $\lim_{x\to x_0} G(x)= 0$, and $\lim_{x\to x_0}F(x)\neq 0$, what can we say about $\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{F(x)}{G(x)}$?

Comment: If $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ are same degree polynomial then the answer is just the ratio of their(highest degree term) coefficient  and if not then $\infty$.Am i right @5xum Sir

Comment: @raihanhossain You are wrong. For example, take $G(x)=x$ and $F(x)=x+1$, and take a look at their limits when $x\to 0$.